# Select HTML item using VBA Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I tried to extract somes information from ALibaba.com but i didn't success to select Supplier in the list

[image]

Here is the html code

[image]

```
 Set Post = IEdoc_ALi.getElementsByClassName("ui-searchbar-type-option").Item
 Post.all(2).innerText = "Suppliers"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's a link that needs clicking. You can use a css [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector to target the relevant node and then apply the `click` method.

```
Option Explicit   

Public Sub SelectSuppliers()   
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.alibaba.com/"
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.querySelector("[data-value=suppliers]").Click

        Stop '<Delete me later
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Accepted. As this is going to help me do something I was planning (with a different wbsite that is)